# How do I generate a mapping from numbers to colors in R?

Tags: r, colors

In R, I can easily generate a color ramp, for example colorRampPalette. The following produces a sequence of five colors, from blue to red:

```
> mypal <- colorRampPalette( c( "blue", "red" ) )( 5 )
> mypal
[1] "#0000FF" "#3F00BF" "#7F007F" "#BF003F" "#FF0000"
```

How can I easily map a vector of numbers on this palette? Say, I have a vector of numbers between 0 and 10, like this:

```
x <- c( 1, 9, 8.5, 3, 3.4, 6.2 )
```

I would like a function, say `map2color`, such that when I run `map2color( mypal, x )`, I get

```
#0000FF, #FF0000, #FF0000, #3F00BF, #3F00BF, #BF003F
```

I usually do something like the following

```
mypalette[ findInterval( x, seq( 0, 10, length.out= 6 ), rightmost.closed= T ) ]
```

but maybe there is a better solution OOB, automatically generating a color scale for a numeric vector.

Comment: You might have more luck in the HCL colourspace and varying the luminance, see `?hcl`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My colourscheme package on R-Forge does that:

https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/colourscheme/

its primary purpose is to create functions that map numeric values (not just integer colour numbers) to colours. The vignette is the best documentation once you've got it installed.

Comment: Sounds interesting! May I ask why you did not submit it to CRAN? (I can't install it with install.packages, had to use svn)

Comment: It was a fairly quick ad-hoc hack, the documentation is a bit rubbish, and I'd hoped it might gather some momentum and usage - but it never did...

Comment: Yeah, but I for one would and did not find it, because it was not on CRAN :-)

Comment: Sadly, package ‘colourscheme’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1).

Answer (score 12):

Here's a map2color function:

```
map2color<-function(x,pal,limits=NULL){
    if(is.null(limits)) limits=range(x)
    pal[findInterval(x,seq(limits[1],limits[2],length.out=length(pal)+1), all.inside=TRUE)]
}


 map2color(0:11,rainbow(200),limits=c(1,10))
[1] "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#FFA800FF" "#ADFF00FF" "#05FF00FF" "#00FFA3FF"
[7] "#00ABFFFF" "#0003FFFF" "#A600FFFF" "#FF00B0FF" "#FF0008FF" "#FF0008FF"
 map2color(0:11,rainbow(200))
[1] "#FF0000FF" "#FF8A00FF" "#EBFF00FF" "#61FF00FF" "#00FF29FF" "#00FFB3FF"
[7] "#00BAFFFF" "#0030FFFF" "#5900FFFF" "#E300FFFF" "#FF0091FF" "#FF0008FF"


mypal <- colorRampPalette( c( "blue", "red" ) )( 5 )
x <- c( 1, 9, 8.5, 3, 3.4, 6.2 )
map2color(x,mypal)
"#0000FF" "#FF0000" "#FF0000" "#3F00BF" "#3F00BF" "#BF003F"
```

I needed something like this to create a colorramp that would be consistent across different samples of data, so I added an xlim parameter.  Thanks for the reminder of the findInterval function in your question.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest thing I can think of is discretizing your variable x with `cut` and then using the resultant factor to index a color Palettes like `heat.colors` or `cm.colors`

```
f <- function(x,n=10){
    heat.colors(n)[cut(x,n)]
}
```

see `?heat.colors` for more details of Palettes.

This function will give you are color vector corresponding to `x` of varying granularity proportional to `n`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
> colorRampPalette(c('blue', 'red'))(length(x))[rank(x)]
[1] "#0000FF" "#FF0000" "#CC0032" "#3300CC" "#660099" "#990065"
```

Comment: but this is different from  the OP result, isn't?

Comment: No, this would not work, close numbers should have very similar colors. Take c( 1, 2, 3, 200 ); the first three numbers should all be close to the beginning of the color scala, and using ranks the 3 would already be blue.

Comment: This may not solve January's problem, but it solves different problems, the case where you want to distinguish all numbers in case of 1,2,3 and 200