# plot3d() - How to change z axis surface color to heat map color

Tags: r, rgl

[image: Graph Plot]

In the above image the surface colored in z axis (like heat map). I am using plot3d()

```
plot3d(data$x, data$y, data$z, name = 'Plotly3D graph', type = 'l', axes=F)
```

I have to repeat the same color as of in the image. By using above code I can get the 3D square but I dont know where to set the color of z axis as same as the image. Please help me in plot3D. If full code is needed will post if required.

Here is sample code:

```
data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(),1)

# retrieve age column from csv file 
var1 <- data1$age

z1 <- rep(1, times=length(var1))

plot3d(var1, length(var1), z1, type="l", xaxt='n', yaxt='n', xlab="Jitter in 
ns", ylab="Counts", size=0.05,expand=0.75, col=color[zcol],
ticktype="detailed", zlab="")
```

Comment: How to do it depends on the form of the input, so you should post a runnable example.

Comment: See below i have answered

Comment: I've edited your sample code into your question; that's the normal place to put it.  You should delete your answer, and continue to edit the code so that others can run it.  We don't have your dataset!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one version, using a function from one of the answers to [How do I generate a mapping from numbers to colors in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006211/how-do-i-generate-a-mapping-from-numbers-to-colors-in-r).

```
# A function based on Dave X's answer to the colour mapping question
map2color <- function(x, pal, limits = range(x)){
  pal[findInterval(x, seq(limits[1], limits[2], length.out = length(pal) + 1), 
                   all.inside=TRUE)]
}

persp3d(volcano, col = map2color(volcano, rainbow(100)))
```

This produces this image:

[image]

To produce solid edges ("curtains" in plot3D), just surround the data with extra rows and columns of its minimum value.  For example,

```
m <- min(volcano)
volcano2 <- cbind(m, rbind(m, volcano, m), m)
```

To make the edges look flat, you need to add `x` and `y` values, just a tiny bit outside the original ones:

```
x <- c(0.9999, 1:nrow(volcano), nrow(volcano) + 0.0001)
y <- c(0.9999, 1:ncol(volcano), ncol(volcano) + 0.0001)
persp3d(x, y, volcano2, col = map2color(volcano2, heat.colors(100)))
```

I switched the palette to `heat.colors` just for some variety.

[image]

Comment: I want the surface background color to be changed not the plot color. Can you please help me on that end? Thanks for your support

Comment: I don't know what the "surface background color" is.  Which part of my image should get the color?

Comment: On "z axis" there is white surface color above "valcano" label that should be changed to heat map color