# How to Draw a three-dimensional graph in R

Tags: r, plot, rgl

```
f(x,y)= (1/25)*(20-x)/x   10<x<20, x/2 <y <x
        0                   o.t
```

I have to create this image through this expression.
[image]

but 
[image]

```
x <- seq(10, 20, length=20)
y <- seq(10, 20, length=20)
f <- function(x,y){(1/25)*(20-x)/5}
z <- outer(x,y,f)
persp(x,y,z,theta=30,phi=30, expand=0.5,col=rainbow(19), border=NA)
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Welcome. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for best practices when posting questions.

Comment: If the answer below is satisfactory, you should "accept" it.  If not, you should explain what else you want, and its author may try to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should mask `z` based on the constraint. As a suggestion, you can use an amazing interactive `rgl` package in R.

```
#source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079316/plot3d-how-to-change-z-axis-surface-color-to-heat-map-color
map2color <- function(x, pal, limits = range(x,na.rm=T)){
  pal[findInterval(x, seq(limits[1], limits[2], length.out = length(pal) + 1), 
               all.inside=TRUE)]
}

x <- seq(10, 20, length=20)
y <- seq(10, 20, length=20)
mask <- sapply(x,function(m) sapply(y,function(n) if((n>m/2)&(n<m)){(1/25)*(20-m)/5}else{ NA }))
z <- outer(x,y,f)
z <- z * mask
#persp(x,y,z, col= map2color(z, rainbow(100)),border = NA)
library(rgl)
persp3d(x,y,z,col = map2color(z, rainbow(100)),theta=30,phi=30)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@SRhm's answer is probably the best choice, but if you want to live on the bleeding edge, you can get rid of the jagged diagonal edge using a development version of `rgl` (from R-forge), at least version 0.100.8.

This version supports triangulations with boundaries using the `tripack` package.  So you set up a grid of values over the x-y range, then define the boundaries of the region using the equations, and you get smooth edges.  For example:

```
library(tripack)
library(rgl)
g <- expand.grid(x=10:20, y=5:20)
keep <- with(g, 10 < x & x < 20 & x/2 < y & y < x)
g2 <- g[keep,]
tri <- tri.mesh(g2)

# Set up boundary constraints
cx <- c(10:20, 20: 10)
cy <- c(seq(5, 10, len=11), 20:10)
tri2 <- add.constraint(tri, cx, cy, reverse = TRUE)

# This isn't necessary, but shows where the formula will be evaluated
plot(tri2)
```

[image: triangulation]

It might be better to fill in some of the left and right edges with more points to avoid those big triangles,
but skip that for now.

```
z <- with(tri2, (1/25)*(20-x)/x)
# Now plot it, using the map2color function @SRhm found:
#source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079316/plot3d-how-to-change-z-axis-surface-color-to-heat-map-color
map2color <- function(x, pal, limits = range(x,na.rm=T)){
  pal[findInterval(x, seq(limits[1], limits[2], length.out = length(pal) + 1), 
               all.inside=TRUE)]
}
persp3d(tri2, z, col = map2color(z, rainbow(100)))
```

After rotation, you get this view:

[image: persp3d view]